# Problem using multiple jquery ajax request in a single page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hello i am working on a PHP Project where i need to load some request using ajax request. Below are my request function.

Function One: When showNotify event is click i call the ajax request to get content and use ajaxStart to show spinner untill the content is fully ready!

```
 //* First click load nofication
$(document).on('click', '#showNotify', function() {
    let check = $(this).data('check');
    if(check === 0) {
        //* Process notification
        $(this).attr('data-check', 1);
        
        //* Load ajax request
        $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
            $('#notify-wait').show();
        });

        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            $('#notify-wait').hide();
            $('#list-noti').show();
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '/list-dd-notifications',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function() {
                $('#notif-unread').hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Function Two: i need to check from the server side to see if user has a new unready notify and show up the new notification sign.

```
function checkNewFotify() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/check-notifications',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data) {
                if($('#notif-unread').is(":hidden"))
                {
                    $('#notif-unread').show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($('#notif-unread').is(":visible"))
                {
                    $('#notif-unread').hide();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

//* check for new notification
setInterval(() => {
    checkNewFotify();
}, 5000);
```

Problem: Any time the showNotify is dropdown at first it show the spinner the loader until the request is fully loaded also if the function **checkNewFotify** is doing is job by refreshing every 5 secs to check the server for new notification the ajaxStart in **showNotify** will be affected by showing the spinner loader every time the **checkNewFotify** is refreshing in background.

Please how can i stop it from showing the spinner loader whil it refreshing every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the global option to false on the ajax on `checkNewFotify()` this will prevent handlers like ajaxStart from firing.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/check-notifications',
    method: 'GET',
    global: false,
});
```